# Make upload and download file facility in a project. Where do I start?

Tags: jsp

I've test papers(.xls) in jsp to be uploaded and students will be submitting back after solving them.

How do I make it possible?
I have no idea of uploading files and downloading. What would I look for then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Internet is filled with examples of how to upload files using JSP/Servlets and this site also has some nice questions and answers regarding this.

So here are few sites which explain how to proceed:

1. [How to upload using JSP/Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2422468/1761033): This question uses the Apache Commons file upload api
2. Here is a [nice tutorial](http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet-file-upload-example.html) to explain how to handle file upload with apache commons.
3. Another [example](http://www.javaquery.com/2011/12/how-to-upload-file-using-jsp-servlet.html) using the Apache Commons file upload.
4. Did I say there are many examples: Here is [another one](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/05/28/how-to-file-uploading-using-jspservlet/) and whats more they also have the full source code download [here](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/fileupload.war).

Phew! So many examples. Let me know if you are still looking for something specific.

The first and last link is a really good starting point.